# NGit rebase creates new commit

Tags: c#, git

I've got some functionality working in git that I'm trying to port to NGit.  My git script looks like this:

```
git add . 
git commit -a -m "Auto Commit"
git fetch
git rebase
git push
```

(I left out the conflict handling details, they're not relevant here.)

Porting this to NGit, I end up with the following:

```
// Open a connection to the repository
Git _git = Git.Open(MyRepoPath);

// Add all new files to the commit.
_git.Add().AddFilepattern(".").Call();

// execute the commit, but don't push yet.
_git.Commit().SetMessage(CommitMsg).SetAll(true).Call();

// fetch all remote files
_git.Fetch().Call();

// rebase 
_git.Rebase().SetUpstream("FETCH_HEAD").Call();

// push all changes
_git.Push().Call();
```

Looks pretty much the same...  The only difference that I see is that on my git server, every time the NGit program runs, there is a new commit that's pushed to the repository.  This doesn't seem to be the case when I'm simply running the script via msysgit on the same machine. (i.e. if no files are changed, there is nothing generated on the server.)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  Any smart ideas on how to push only if there is anything different from the local to the remote after the rebase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question... hopefully this helps someone out.  I implemented an "isDirty" function (since NGit doesn't seem to implement IsClean from the JGit library) as follows:

```
private bool IsDirty(Status status)
{
    return status.GetAdded().Count + status.GetChanged().Count + status.GetConflicting().Count +
           status.GetMissing().Count + status.GetModified().Count + status.GetRemoved().Count +
           status.GetUntracked().Count > 0;
}
```

Then I check this before doing the add/commit:

```
 // Check if anything needs a'doin'
 if(IsDirty(_git.Status().Call()))
 {
    // Add all new files to the commit.
     _git.Add().AddFilepattern(".").Call();

     // execute the commit, but don't push yet.
     _git.Commit().SetMessage(CommitMsg).SetAll(true).Call();
  }
```

And it now it works the same as the script above.  Cool!